# Symfony2 form events and model transformers

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm getting tied in knots trying to wrestle with Symfony2's form builders, events and transformers... hopefully somebody here is more experienced and can help out!

I have a form field (select drop-down) which contains some values (a shortlist) which maps to an Entity. One of these options is "other". Assume there's no AJAX for now and when a user submits the form I want to detect if they chose 'other' (or any other option not in the shortlist). If they chose one of these options then the full list of options should be shown, otherwise just show the shortlist. Should be easy, right? ;)

So, I have my Form Type and it displays the basic shortlist just fine. The code looks something like this:

```
namespace Company\ProjectBundle\Form\Type;

use ...

class FancyFormType extends AbstractType {
    private $fooRepo;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em, FooRepository $fooRepo)
    {
        $this->fooRepo = $fooRepo;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        /** @var Bar $bar */
        $bar = $builder->getData();
        $fooTransformer = new FooToStringTransformer($options['em']);

        $builder
            ->add($builder
                ->create('linkedFoo', 'choice', array(
                    'choices' => $this->fooRepo->getListAsArray(
                        $bar->getLinkedfoo()->getId()
                    ),
                ))
                ->addModelTransformer($fooTransformer)
            )
        ;

        // ...

    }

    // ...
}
```

Now, I want to check the value submitted so I use a Form Event Listener as follows.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    // ... This code comes just after the snippet shown above

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        /** @var EntityManager $em */
        $em = $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOption('em');

        $data = $event->getData();
        if (empty($data['linkedFoo'])) return;
        $selectedFoo = $data['linkedfoo'];

        $event->getForm()->add('linkedFoo', 'choice', array(
            'choices' => $em
                ->getRepository('CompanyProjectBundle:FooShortlist')
                ->getListAsArray($selectedFoo)
            ,
        ));
        //@todo - needs transformer?
    });
}
```

However, it fails with an error message like this:

```
Notice: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\Company\ProjectBundle\Entity\Foo could not be converted to int in \path\to\project\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php line 458
```

I presume this error is because when the `linkedFoo` was over-written it removed the `modelTransformer`? I tried various ways of accessing a builder in the event's closure but this didn't seem to work (the return values were unexpected). Is there some other method I should be using in the event other than `$event->getForm()->add()`? Or is there a more fundamental problem with my approach here?

Basically I don't want to mess with the `linkedFoo` field's config/transformers/labels *except* to change the choices available... is there some other way to do that? E.g. something like `$form->getField()->updateChoices()`?

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

C

P.S. is there any better documentation or discussion of the forms, events, etc than on the Symfony website? E.g. what's the difference between PRE_SET_DATA, PRE_SUBMIT, SUBMIT, etc? When are they fired? What should they be used for? How does inheritance work with custom form fields? What is a Form and a Builder, how do they interact and when should you deal with each? How, when and why should you use the FormFactory you can access through `$form->getConfig()->getFormFactory()`? Etc..

---

Edit: In response to Florian's suggestion here's some more info about things that were tried but do not work:

If you try to get the FormBuilder within the event like this:

```
/** @var FormBuilder $builder */
$builder = $event->getForm()->get('linkedFoo')->getConfig();

$event->getForm()->add($builder
    ->create('linkedFoo', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $newChoices,
        'label'   =>'label',
    ))
    ->addModelTransformer(new FooToStringTransformer($em))
);
```

Then you get the error:

```
FormBuilder methods cannot be accessed anymore once the builder is turned
into a FormConfigInterface instance.
```

So then you try something like Florian suggested, i.e.

```
$event->getForm()->add('linkedFoo', 'choice', array(
    'choices' => $newChoices,
));
$event->getForm()->get('linkedFoo')->getConfig()->addModelTransformer(new FooToStringTransformer($em));
```

...but you get this error instead:

```
Notice: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\Company\ProjectBundle\Entity\Foo could not be converted to int 
in C:\path\to\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ChoiceList.php line 458
```

Which seems to suggest that the second line (which adds the ModelTransformer) is never called because the `->add()` call is failing before you can get there.

Comment: complex subject indeed :) First: what version of symfony/form are you using ?

Comment: Using Symfony-2.3.6 at the moment, updating the 2.3.x branch as I go.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Thanks to the ideas from sstok (on github), I think I've got it working now. The key is to create a customised Form Type and then use that to add the ModelTransformer.

Create the custom Form Type:

```
namespace Caponica\MagnetBundle\Form\Type;

use ...

class FooShortlistChoiceType extends AbstractType {
    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em                   = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $fooTransformer = new FooToStringTransformer($this->em);

        $builder
            ->addModelTransformer($fooTransformer)
        ;
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'fooShortlist';
    }
}
```

Create a service definition for the new Type:

```
company_project.form.type.foo_shortlist:
    class: Company\ProjectBundle\Form\Type\FooShortlistChoiceType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: fooShortlist }
    arguments:
        - @doctrine.orm.entity_manager
```

The main form's code now looks something like this:

```
namespace Company\ProjectBundle\Form\Type;

use ...

class FancyFormType extends AbstractType {
    private $fooRepo;

    public function __construct(FooRepository $fooRepo)
    {
        $this->fooRepo = $fooRepo;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        /** @var Bar $bar */
        $bar = $builder->getData();
        $fooTransformer = new FooToStringTransformer($options['em']);

        $builder
            ->add('linkedFoo', 'fooShortlist', array(
                'choices' => $this->fooRepo->getListAsArray(
                    $bar->getLinkedfoo()->getId()
                ),
            ))
        ;

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
            /** @var EntityManager $em */
            $em = $event->getForm()->getConfig()->getOption('em');

            $data = $event->getData();
            if (empty($data['linkedFoo'])) return;
            $selectedFoo = $data['linkedFoo'];

            $event->getForm()->add('linkedFoo', 'fooShortlist', array(
                'choices'       => $em->getRepository('CaponicaMagnetBundle:FooShortlist')->getListAsArray($selectedFoo),
                'label'         => 'label'
            ));
        });

        // ...

    }

    // ...
}
```

The key is that this method allows you to embed the ModelTransformer within the custom field type so that, whenever you add a new instance of this type it automatically adds the ModelTransformer for you and prevents the previous loop of "can't add a field without a transformer AND can't add a transformer without a field"

Comment: why do you have to manually transform the choices in your listener while you already attach the transformer which should do that for you?

Answer (score 1):

Your listener looks (almost :) ) ok.

Just use PRE_SUBMIT. 
In that case, `$event->getData()` will be the raw form data (an array) that is sent. 
`$selectedFoo` will potentailly contain "other".

If it is the case, you will replace the "short" 'choice' field  with a full one, by using formFactory in the listener.

```php
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
    $data = $event->getData();
    if (empty($data['linkedFoo']) || $data['linkedFoo'] !== 'other') {
        return;
    }

    // now we know user choose "other"
    // so we'll change the "linkedFoo" field with a "fulllist"


    $event->getForm()->add('linkedFoo', 'choice', array(
        'choices' => $fullList, // $em->getRepository('Foo')->getFullList() ?
    ));
    $event->getForm()->get('linkedFoo')->getConfig()->addModelTransformer(new FooTransformer);
});
```

You asked so much questions I don't know where to start.

Concerning dataTransformers: 
until you want to transform raw data into a different representation ("2013-01-01" -> new DateTime("2013-01-01")), then you don't need transformers.

Comment: I have to dash so not able to look at this thoroughly yet. However, I thought I needed to use PRE_SUBMIT because I want to handle the case where the user submits the form with the shortlist "OTHER" option in it (e.g. if the AJAX update fails). I don't think that the PRE_SET_DATA has visibility of this.

Comment: how, yes sorry, it's PRE_SUBMIT that should be used to get posted data. (my bad, post updated).

Comment: OK, just had a chance to look at this and the proposed listener in your example is effectively the same as mine... it's just that I use $repo->getListAsArray() to return an array instead of $fullList. The problem is that using getForm()->add() in the listener over-writes the previous field settings and removes the modelTransformer that was originally added. So how do we add the modelTransformer back?

Comment: answer updated with an experiment: using `$form->getConfig()->addModelTransformer();`

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't get us there either :-/ I had already tried something similar. I'll update my OP with some more details of what happens if you try this.

Comment: soo, your transformer is actually called right ? [Edit, ha maybe not). however, What does this transformer do ? can you share its code ?

Comment: Other question: what is the value of $newChoices ?

Comment: You can see the ModelTransformer here: http://pastebin.com/dnXFFi3F . $newChoices is a simple array of strings (not objects), e.g. { 'aa': 'Option 1', 'bb': 'Option 2', 'zz': 'Other' }. It all works fine except for the form event.

Comment: I think you should not use a model transformer but directly pass an array of objects in "choices" (maybe an ObjectChoiceList if needed). Or if possible, use "entity" type, wich makes the id => entity transition by himself.

Comment: Isn't that kind of the point and purpose of ModelTransformers? (To allow you to use something other than the objects when building/displaying the form) There are various workarounds I could do, but I would like to know how one is supposed to use a ModelTransformer in this circumstance! Either by re-adding the transformer or by dynamically changing the field's options without having to over-write the entire field.

Comment: using this with `PRE_SET_DATA` tends to `FormConfigBuilder methods cannot be accessed anymore once the builder is turned into a FormConfigInterface instance.`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is still looking for a better way to add/re-add a Model Transformer inside form events, I think that the best solution is the one from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40868973/9751856) all credits go to @Toilal for this brilliant solution

So if you implement the ModelTransformerExtension and define it as a service, and change some code, for example, from

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
            array($this, 'onPreSetData')
        );
    $builder->add(
                $builder
                    ->create('customer', TextType::class, [
                        'required' => false,
                        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control selectize-customer'),
                    ])
                    ->addModelTransformer(new CustomerToId($this->customerRepo))
            )
            ;
}
```

to something like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
                array($this, 'onPreSetData')
            );
    $builder->add('customer', TextType::class, [
                'required' => false,
                'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control selectize-customer'),
                'model_transformer' => new CustomerToId($this->customerRepo),
            ]
        )
        ;
}
```

And now if we remove and re-add the desired field inside the eventlistener function, the Model Transformer for the field will not be lost.

```
protected function onPreSetData(FormEvent $event)
{
    $form = $event->getForm();
    $formFields = $form->all();
    foreach ($formFields as $key=>$value){
        $config = $form->get($key)->getConfig();
        $type = get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType());
        $options = $config->getOptions();

        //you can make changes to options/type for every form field here if you want 

        if ($key == 'customer'){
            $form->remove($key);
            $form->add($key, $type, $options);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this is a simple example. I've used this solution to easily process a form to have multiple field states in different places.

Answer (score 1):

Inheriting `$builder` from the parent scope using an annonymous function as event handler would also work.

```php
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) use ($builder) {
    $data = $event->getData();

    if (empty($data['linkedFoo'])) {
       return;
    }
    $builder->add('linkedFoo', 'choice', [
        'choices' => $this->fooRepo->getListAsArray(
            $data->getLinkedfoo()->getId()
         ),
    ]);
    $builder->get('linkedFoo')
        ->addModelTransformer(
            new FooTransformer()
        );

});
```