# Symfony2 - How to use a Data Transformer inside EventListeners

Tags: php, symfony

- I need to use an Event Listener since I need different things to be displayed in my form whether it is new or an already existing entity. I can manage that.
- I need a Data Transformer, to display the entity as text, which is something I also can do.

=> However, I fail in doing the 2 (Data Transformer+Event Listener) at the same time. I get the error:
"Error: Call to a member function add() on a non-object". If I replace $builder par $form, I get the following error: Attempted to call an undefined method named "create" of class "Symfony\Component\Form\Form".

That works:

```
 $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event){
        $element = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (!$element || null === $element->getId()) { //new entity
            $form->add(...);
        } else { //exist already
            //...
        }
```

That also works:

```
$builder->add( $builder->create('element', 'text')->addModelTransformer($transformer));
```

But I cannot make the 2 working at the same time.

```
    $transformer = new ElementObjToStringTransformer($this->em);
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event){
        $element = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        if (!$element || null === $element->getId()) { //new entity
            $builder->add( $builder->create('element', 'text')->addModelTransformer($transformer));
        } else { //exist already
            //...
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can define data transformer as service and inject it into Listener, but using it this way looks very strange. I think, this is bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: You can´t add the transformer inside the listener because the form is already locked.

Long answer: There are some solutions. The most common, at least for me, is to a create a Custom form type where you add your transformer.
Then you add your custom form how you would normally do in the event listener:

```
class ElementCustomType extends AbstractType {

    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
            ->addModelTransformer(new ElementObjToStringTransformer($this->em))
        ;
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'elementCustom';
    }
}
```

Define your form as a service:

```
 app.form.type.custom_element:
    class: AppBundle\Form\Type\ElementCustomType
    arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: elementCustom }
```

Use the form in the listener as your would normally do:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event){
        $element = $event->getData();
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $form->add('element', 'elementCustom')
    });
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks a lot. Quick and right to the point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it saved my day. This approach is also applicable for Symfony5.2. I needed to apply transformer for `filed_1`, only if value is set in `field_2` by user. So, I've created 2 custom fields - with and without transformer. Since I wasn't succeed in applying transformer for `field_1` conditionally in my subscriber, I just add one or another custom field there depending on value in `field_2`. And it seems to work!

Answer (score 3):

I have wrote a Form Extension to support this use case without changing type of fields.

**1) Create extension class.**

```
namespace AppBundle\Form\Extension\ModelTransformerExtension

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ModelTransformerExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension {

    public function getExtendedType() {
        return FormType::class;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        if (isset($options['model_transformer'])) {
            $builder->addModelTransformer($options['model_transformer']);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array('model_transformer' => null));
    }
}
```

**2) Register this extension as an application service.**

```
services:
    app.form.extension.model_transformer:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Extension\ModelTransformerExtension
        tags:
            - { name: form.type_extension, extended_type: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\FormType }
```

**3) Define `model_transformer` option to any DataTransformer implement when building the form.**

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function ($event) {
        $builder = $event->getForm();

        $builder->add('myField', TextType::class, array(
            'model_transformer' => new MyModelTransformer()
        ));
    });
}
```

This idea can be extended to support `addViewTransformer` method as well.

Comment: Works for me. Thanks !

Comment: This is great. Thanks