# ChoiceType multiple attribute according to entity property (how to choose between returning a collection of entities or one entity)

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a quiz project with the Symfony framework (version 4.4) and Doctrine as ORM.

There is a ManyToOne relation between the Answer and the Question entities, as for the QuizQuestion and Answer entities. I use the QuizQuestion entity to make the link between a quiz, a question, and the selected answer(s).

I use a EntityType "QuizQuestionType" with the multiple attribute set to true to collect answers, and it works as expected :

```
$builder
            ->add('answers', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Answer::class,
                'choices' => $this->fillAnswers($quizQuestion),
                'expanded' => true,
                'multiple' => true,
            ]);
```

The thing is, I want to be able to setup question as multiple or single choice. If I set the EntityType multiple attibute to false, I got the error :

> Entity of type "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" passed to the
> choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the
> entity manager?

I could use two answers entities with a OneToMany and a OneToOne relations, but it seems a really poor design to me.

I wonder how it can be done, ideally with a property in the Question entity that indicates if it is a multiple or unique choice question. That will allow me to simply declare it in the backend (because technically, a multiple choice question may have only one good answer, so I can't calculate it by the number of answers).

Do you have any idea on how I can achieve this ?

Here is the conceptual data model :

[CDM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFaCJ.png)

The answer entity : https://pastebin.com/kiRTHnvL

The QuizQuestion entity : https://pastebin.com/wL3v9fwT

Thank you for your help,

### EDIT 01/08/2020

As suggested by @victor-vasiloi, I added an event listener to the form type so I can setup the correct extensions. I was not able to add the transformer though. I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33789883/symfony2-how-to-use-a-data-transformer-inside-eventlisteners/40868973#40868973) and created an extension to use a data transformer from the event listener :

### QuizQuestionType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
       $builder
            ->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) use ($builder){
                $quizQuestion = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                if ($quizQuestion->getQuestion()->getIsMultiple()){
                    $form->add('answers', EntityType::class, [
                        'class' => Answer::class,
                        'choices' => $this->fillAnswers($quizQuestion),
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => true,
                    ]);
                } else {
                    $form->add('answers', EntityType::class, [
                        'class' => Answer::class,
                        'choices' => $this->fillAnswers($quizQuestion),
                        'expanded' => true,
                        'multiple' => false,
                        'model_transformer' => new CollectionToAnswerTransformer(),
                    ]);
                }
            })
        ;

    }
```

### ModelTransformerExtension

```
class ModelTransformerExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{

    public static function getExtendedTypes(): iterable
    {
        // return FormType::class to modify (nearly) every field in the system
        return [FormType::class];
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

        if (isset($options['model_transformer'])) {
            $builder->addModelTransformer($options['model_transformer']);
        }
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) {
        parent::configureOptions($resolver);

        $resolver->setDefaults(array('model_transformer' => null));
    }
}
```

Now the form could be loaded. When submitting though (in a case of a unique answer with radio buttons), a CollectionToArrayTranformer was giving the following error :

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Answer", "array" given at
> property path "answers".

I tried a custom CollectionToAnswerTransformer, that looks like this :

```
class CollectionToAnswerTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * @param mixed $collection
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function transform($collection)
    {
        if (null === $collection){
            return '';
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($collection as $answer){
                return $answer;
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $answer
     * @return ArrayCollection|mixed
     */
    public function reverseTransform($answer)
    {
        $collection = new ArrayCollection();
        $collection->add($answer);
        return $collection;
    }
}
```

But with no better results. I get the error :

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Answer", "instance of
> Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection" given at property path
> "answers".

It looks like an issue with the reverse transformer method, but if I change it to return an entity, I got the opposite error :

> Could not determine access type for property "answers" in class
> "App\Entity\QuizQuestion": The property "answers" in class
> "App\Entity\QuizQuestion" can be defined with the methods
> "addAnswer()", "removeAnswer()" but the new value must be an array or
> an instance of \Traversable, "App\Entity\Answer" given...

I think I'm almost at it, but I don't know if my transformer is the way to go or if it is easier than that...

Comment: What is your version of symfony ? Some code is always a good idea ;-).

Comment: You are conflicting the way the entitytype is meant to be used. you do have a ManyToMany relation so to use the EntityType out of the box, you have to configure it to multiple true. you could however try to set an attribute that will limit the number of selections to one html-wise.

Comment: @olidem, I understand what you mean. I was searching to put the logic into the Type, it seemed cleaner to me (plus having the correct display). I think I almost achieved that with the model transformer, just got a last issue with it.

Answer (score 2):

To setup questions with single choice you could use a radio button, and checkboxes for multiple choices.
Radio button is expanded "true" and multiple "false".
Checkbox is expanded "true" and multiple "true".
Code example that display checkboxes:

```
$builder
    ->add('filter', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => 'FilterBundle:Filter',
    'multiple' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'required' => true
));
```

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons

And if you want to define it for each question before displaying, there could be a field on your question entity (for example a boolean "multiple").

Comment: This is what I done and it works perfectly when I set the multiple and expanded attributes to true. But it throws the error "Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Form\Exception\RuntimeException: "Entity of type "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?"" when I set the multiple attribute to false. I update the post to add more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically set the `multiple` option based on the given Question using a form event listener on the `Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` event, here's where you can learn more about [dynamically modifying the form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) and [form events](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/events.html).

Using the same logic, when the `multiple` option is set to `true`, you can add the `Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DataTransformer\CollectionToArrayTransformer` model transformer to the answers field like this `$builder->get('answers')->addModelTransformer(new CollectionToArrayTransformer());` which will ensure the transformation between the Doctrine Collection and the choices array (including single choice).

Comment: I didn't know the Transformer concept, it seems very relevant. I'm looking into it and the form events, thank you.

Comment: @pab.node maybe also share your form types.

Comment: This was the way to go I think. I've updated the post to reflect the changes.

Comment: unfortunately not. I updated the post with the lastest information. It made me think about the approach and the conceptual model though. I went with single choice questions only for the moment. If you have an idea of what was not working, I still have a branch to make some test. I'd like to understand and mark this thread as solved !

Comment: @pab.node maybe try from scratch and upload to GitHub, so I can quickly test it.