# Symfony extends a form with dependencies from submit data

Tags: symfony-forms

I am trying to extends my form, but I dont know how to do it ...

**The problem**

My parent formType depends of a option. But I want provide that option from the child form. In [symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms) they explain a method to add dynamic fields that depends on submit data. But if It have a field with DataTransformer?, because in FormInterface I can't add it.

**The code**

```php
class TransactionApiType extends AbstractApiType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
         $app = $options['app'];
         
         $builder
            ->add('gamer', TextType::class)->addModelTransformer(new GamerExternalIdToStringCreateIfNotExistTransformer($em, $app))
            ;
    }
    
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
           'data_class' => Transaction::class,
        ))
           ->setAllowedTypes('app', ['AppBundle\Entity\App'])
    ;
    }

}


class TransactionMultiAppConfByAppApiType extends TransactionApiType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('app_id',
           EntityType::class,
           [
           'property_path' => 'app',
           'required'      => true,
           'description'   => 'App id',
           'class'         => App::class,
        ])
       ;

       // I need pass $options['app'] here to work (App will be submitted),
       // How can do? or other possibilities
       parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
       $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => Transaction::class,
        )
        ;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add fields with DataTransformers in formEvents are not enabled https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9355

But there is a "hack"
related here [Symfony2 form events and model transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382017/symfony2-form-events-and-model-transformers) (Summary it needs create a customType...)

My solution was

```php
class TransactionMultiAppConfByAppApiType extends TransactionApiType
{

    // ...
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options);

    $optionsApp = $builder->get('gamer')->getAttributes()['data_collector/passed_options'];
    $builder->remove('gamer');

    $builder->get('app_id')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($em, $optionsApp) {

            /** @var App $app */
            $app = $event->getForm()->getData();
            $f = $event->getForm()->getParent();

            if ($app)
            {
                $f
                    ->add('gamer', GamerIdWithExternalIdCustomType::class, $optionsApp + ['em' => $em, 'app' => $app])
                ;
            }

    });

    // ...

}

class GamerIdWithExternalIdCustomType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer(new GamerExternalIdToStringCreateIfNotExistTransformer($options['em'], $options['app']));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
    $resolver
        ->setRequired([
            'em',
            'app',
        ]);
    }
}
```